# How to pass a parameter/argument to webform using clean urls?

Tags: webforms

I've found [a post which explains how to pass a parameter/argument/referer to webform](http://drupal.org/node/881226).

It works fine, but I get an ugly URL.
Is there any way to do this using a clean URL? I mean without using GET parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could solve this using mod_rewrite in your `.htaccess` file. Try something like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/path/to/your/webform/(value)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /path/to/your/webform?param=%1 [L]
```

This way you can do many things but you can't configure that with the drupal UI. Here's an example with more paramters:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/path/to/your/webform/(value1)/(value2)/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /path/to/your/webform?param1=%1&param2=%2&param3=%3 [L]
```

Check out the [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

EDIT: your comment example should look something like that:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/myform/(\d+)$ 
RewriteRule ^.*$ /myform?i=%1 [L]
```

The exact regex at the end depends on your parameters. If you expect only numbers like `1` or `0125` `\d+` should be fine. Check out this [cheatsheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/) for more/other char-classes and regex stuff.

Comment: Hi nonsenz, I tried to implement your code like:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^ficha_inmueble/(value1)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ ficha_inmueble?param1=%1 [L]

The url to rewritte is:
http://localhost/drupal6multilingual/myform/111

But not working...

The url using get parameters is:
http://localhost/drupal6multilingual/myform?i=111

Comment: sorry for my unclear previous comment but break lines doesn't work right when adding comments (i'm using chrome)

Comment: I misstyped: where it says ficha_inmueble read myform

Comment: EDIT: it's not working but I think that reason is I have the webform inside a Panel Page, then drupal makes a different url path that the one I see in the browser address bar. Anyway your answer has been useful to me.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal strictly recognize the `q` i.e. `$_GET['q']` as the page path otherwise redirects to Page Not Found page. Passing the arguments as part of `q`, Drupal menu system must be aware of such arguments place holders. And there arguments can be accessed by `arg([arg-index])`

Passing extra unregistered parameter to any page is only possible by additional GET variables beside `q` and can be accessed by PHP's regular way. i.e. $_GET global array