# Use url alias for page parameters

Tags: 7, uri

I'm new to Drupal and created a basic page in which the clean url is

```
/todo
```

If I want the todo's for a certain month I can do

```
/todo?month=januaray
```

However what I would like to do is provide a clean url which looks like

```
/todo/januaray
```

I tried modifying my `.htaccess` file like explained [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4822/how-to-pass-a-parameter-argument-to-webform-using-clean-urls)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/todo/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /todo?month=%1 [L]
```

But that didn't seem to work. Is there any easy way to achieve this?

Comment: Without knowing the exact functionality you're going for, it's really tough to give an answer.  Can you expand on your question by providing what modules you're working with and what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Look into defining a path with a wildcard using hook_menu.

Comment: If you are using a view with exposed filter, look on this page
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22989/changing-url-of-exposed-filter

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
RewriteRule ^todo/(.*)$ todo?month=$1 [L,QSA]
```

No need for the rewrite condition.

That will internally forward, e.g. `http://example.com/todo/january` to `http://example.com/todo?month=january`.

Make sure you add that code **before** Drupal's main index.php RewriteRule

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it still doesn't seem to work. I pasted it before the `RewriteCond`'s above the `RewriteRule` for index.php. It is telling me `The requested page "/todo/january" could not be found.` I am using the path module too and the system name for the `todo` basic page is `node/3`. Could that effect it at all?

Comment: Ah sorry I misunderstood, didn't read the question properly. Since the alias is stored in Drupal, and isn't a real file, you won't be able to do this with `.htaccess`. I can think of a quick hack you could do in a custom module if that's any good to you?

Comment: I'd rather not do a custom module, I'll just live with the dirtier version of the url.

Answer (score -3):

I would consider using [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) as it is way more flexible and easier to use.

> The Pathauto module automatically generates URL/path aliases for
>   various kinds of content (nodes, taxonomy terms, users) without
>   requiring the user to manually specify the path alias. This allows you
>   to have URL aliases like /category/my-node-title instead of /node/123.
>   The aliases are based upon a "pattern" system that uses tokens which
>   the administrator can change.

Comment: Core path module (which Pathauto uses) doesnt allow parameters in url.